# Does the Fate Accessibility Toolkit cover learning difficulties like ADHD or dyslexia?

Tags: fate, accessibility

Looking at the [description](https://evilhat.itch.io/fate-accessibility-toolkit) I cannot tell if the list on the product page is exhaustive or just a sample of what's inside?

> Discussion of specific disabilities, including blindness, D/deafness and hardness of hearing, mobility issues, dwarfism, chronic illness, autism, depression, anxiety, schizophrenia, bipolarity, and PTSD.

My main query is however about whether it covers anything about learning difficulties such as ADHD, dyslexia etc. ?

While they're perhaps not in the same category of the above disabilities, they still present accessibility barriers.

Comment: Honestly, the Fate Accesibility Toolkit is kind of misnamed; it's better understood as the FATE Inclusion Toolkit. While there is a segment devoted to breaking down some basic mechanical accessibility barriers -  specifically a pretty great section on the translation of somewhat dense RPG Jargon to ASL  -  but for the most part, what is really offered is insight into creating a welcoming and inclusive environment in which players with disabilities can enjoy characters and stories which both reflect and expand upon their own experiences, rather than ignoring or belittling them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Searching my Prototype Edition:

- No hits for 'ADHD'.
- Several hits for 'attention', but never as part of spelling out ADHD.
- Several hits for 'hyper', but mostly as part of 'hypervigilance'/awareness/&c.
- No hits for 'dyslex'.
- Some hits for 'learn', but not as part of a reference to disability.

I do not know whether a more final edition's text differs from the prototype.